# Best way to inject HttpServletResponse into service layer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I know it may not be a best design for a question like this but just for specific requirement.

Current application needs `ServletContext`, `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpServletResponse` in to service layer for a `customized authentication provider`.

Obviously without any specific configuration or inheritance following code:

```
@Component("myAuthenticaionProvider")
public class MyAuthenticaionProvider implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService {
    @Autowired private ServletContext context;
    @Autowired private HttpServletRequest request;
    @Autowired private HttpServletResponse response;
        .......
}
```

must throw exception:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No matching bean of type [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse] found for dependency:
```

Possible solutions I can think of:

1. Intercept `HttpServletRequest` with a filter, but that requires an URL pattern, otherwise will intercept all URLs which I think might be a performance concern?
2. Create a `request` scope bean in spring-security.xml or application-context.xml and then inject into current authentication provider class, to make it capable to get the `HttpServletRequest`. But I think there is something wrong here, as how to initiate the request scope bean?

Then what could be the best practice?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is bad idea, but in an appropriate environment it will work.  `((ServletWebRequest) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getResponse();`. By _appropriate environment_, I mean one where the `RequestAttributes` returned by `getRequestAttributes()` is of type `ServletWebRequest`.

Comment: The chances to get a good solution would be much higher if you described what you want to achieve. To me it looks like you need a filter (especially because of the response object), but you don't want that. So I'm really wondering who calls this service and when (and why).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beyond being a "bad idea" a request object only lives as long as the request. You can't inject it into a singleton due to lifecycle differences. You can pass it in via a method parameter.

The closest solution matching your request is to create a ThreadLocal variable inside a catch all filter and set it there and inject that filter or a delegate to the thread local into your service. I highly suggest you avoid that.

Comment: Interestingly I found `HttpServletRequest` is able to autowired to a service layer. But not sure how it is initiated. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: It is possible to inject a request scoped bean into a singleton, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398651/5226711

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement HttpRequestHandler interface in your authentication provider along with AuthenticationUserDetailsService?

Comment: Thanks so using an interceptor is the best option available so far?

Comment: I can't tell, but what is it you need to achieve in your custom authprovider that requires http servlet?