# Access a request scoped Bean in Service

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-bean

I have a regular bean, which is either (a) `@Scope("request")` or (b) placed in a `HttpServletRequest` via Filter/ Interceptor.

How to access this beans in a `@Service` which is kind of an application scoped singleton?

The reason for this is, because I have a custom object `RequestContext` with some request metadata (mostly informations from custom httpHeaders). For know, i pass this object as parameter to each method on each service, which is a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as the bean is declared as request scope, Spring will take care of the rest.

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public RequestContext requestContext() {
    return new RequestContext();
}
```

Access the bean in the usual way, just autowire it.

```
@Autowired
private RequestContext requestContext;
```

The Service bean will be a singleton, but under the covers, the RequestContext  bean is attached to the thread so you will get a different instance each time a method is called.

**NOTE YOU MUST HAVE A WEB CONTEXT, i.e. RUNNING A WEB SERVER/WEB APP**

Comment: Essex Boy, thanks... some questions: Is this a typical approach to do it? Does injecting the requestContext via constructor of the service work as well?

Comment: @kalamar yes, I have done exactly what you are trying to do, to collect audit data in a request scoped bean, and pass that bean around many different services (which are singletons). Spring will take care of it as long as you declare the bean as request scope, and of course you have a web context so there is a request to attach to.

Comment: hmm, I think, this doesn't work out of the box: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
... have I done something wrong?

Comment: could you add one small detail in order to make your answer complete and acceptable please: `@Scope("request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`

Comment: In addition to that a side note for kotlin users: The request scoped bean has to be `open` and all public val/var properties have to be delegated: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html

Comment: @kalamar I've just added the scope details to the answer, then I saw your comment.

Comment: The problem for me was that I tried to run `System.out.println(myRequestScopedBean)` from singleton bean constructor, and `println` implicitly do `myRequestScopedBean.toString()`, which causes mentioned error. It was hard to find this, so I leave it here for others. Also note, that from Spring 4.3 onward you can use `@RequestScope` alias instead of `@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`.

Comment: @kalamar Could you please provide a sample for this? Im trying to achieve the same but requestScoped bean is retaining information from previous calls.

Comment: @java_4_life can you do something like private javax.inject.Provider<RequestContext> requestContext;

Comment: Should we not be using Provider and not simple @autowired

Answer (score 0):

I had troubles making this work in Kotlin, what finally worked was switching from `@Bean` to `@Component` i.e.

```
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
class RequestContext {
    var context: String = ""
}
```

instead of

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public RequestContext requestContext() {
    return new RequestContext();
}
```

This might be connected to OP's comment about some Kotlin-specific behavior.