# Spring Boot 2 - Identify if method is triggered through controller or async service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot microservice application. I have a requirement such that,

- If method is called through controller (i.e. some user hit API), response should be the username of logged in user.
- If method is called from any non-controller like scheduled task, Async method etc. response should be default user i.e. System.

So, I have a UserDetailService method where I want to write this logic.

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsService
{
    @Autowired
    WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

    @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @Value("${common.serverurl}")
    private String reqUrl;

    public UserReturnData getCurrentUser()
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            UserReturnData userDetails = new UserReturnData();
            userDetails.setId((long) 404);
            userDetails.setUsername("system");
            return userDetails;
        } else
        {
            UserReturnData userDetails = webClientBuilder.build().get().uri(reqUrl + "user/me")
                    .header("Authorization", request.getHeader("Authorization")).retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(UserReturnData.class).block();
            return userDetails;
        }
    }
}
```

To check if method is triggered from controller, I auto-wired HttpServletRequest and compared it to null.
However, when this is triggered from Async service, its throwing exception "Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request"

Is there any other way to identify where the method is getting triggered from. Logic is simple, if controller is involved i.e. if some API call is involved, return logged in user else return default user.

Comment: Will there be a case where the controller calls a service which in turn calls this method ? If yes , what is the expected response ?

Comment: Same.Since there is controller involved at some point, response should be logged in user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SecurityContextHolder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) can be used to check if the current thread is associated with a logged in user. Following method demonstrates the use.

```
public String getCurrentUser() {
    String userName="SYSTEM";
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (authentication!=null && !(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
        userName = authentication.getName();
    }
    return userName;
}
```

Contributed by @Sridhar Patnaik. Taking reference from R.G.'s comment, handled it in below way

1. Removed autowired HttpServletRequest
2. Created request variable
   HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
   .getRequest();
3. Added null check to request. So, if controller is involved, request will be non-null and logged in user will be returned. Else, system user will be returned

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsService
{
    @Autowired
    WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

    /*
     * @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;
     */

    @Value("${common.serverurl}")
    private String reqUrl;

    public UserReturnData getCurrentUser() throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
                    .getRequest();
            if (request == null)
            {
                UserReturnData userDetails = new UserReturnData();
                userDetails.setId((long) 404);
                userDetails.setUsername("system");
                return userDetails;
            }

            else
            {
                UserReturnData userDetails = webClientBuilder.build().get().uri(reqUrl + "user/me")
                        .header("Authorization", request.getHeader("Authorization")).retrieve()
                        .bodyToMono(UserReturnData.class).block();
                return userDetails;
            }

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Something Went Wrong !");
        }}
```

Comment: I do not have spring security enabled for this application. Security is taken care by gateway. So, only when method is called via controller i will be making API call to gateway to get current user, else i will be return system. this is what I want to implement.

Comment: I didnt realize that case.`HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();` can also be used to get the http request bound to the current thread

Answer (score 1):

The proposed approach is sensible, injecting a request-scoped `HttpServletRequest` bean into the singleton service bean will work.  See the answer to [Access a request scoped bean in servce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51398260/access-a-request-scoped-bean-in-service) for more details.

As other answers have suggested, you can also use the security context to determine if the current thread is associated with a **logged in user**. However, that's not sufficient to identify whether the method was called **in the context of an HTTP request**, as opposed to some other non-HTTP request context (e.g. scheduled task).  HTTP requests can be made by anonymous or unauthenticated users, if your Spring Security configuration permits it.